# Warning: Factor contains implicit NA

Tags: r, shiny, na, missing-data

I am new to R and Shiny and I am trying to create an interactive plot with ggplot2. When the user check the checkbox, he has access to a multiple select field to custom the plot.

The original dataframe contains missing values identified as `"N/A"` in `Publisher` and `Year` column. I removed the lines containing NAs with `complete.cases` so it shouldn't have any NA left.

I run my app : OK. I get to the default plot : OK. I check the checkbox : `Warning: Factor 'Publisher' contains implicit NA, consider using 'forcats::fct_explicit_na'`

I'd like to remove this warning, at least understand it. If you have any additional comment please do so : my goal is to get better.

app.R :

```
df<-read.csv("vgsales.csv")
df$Year[df$Year=="N/A"]<-NA
df$Year<-factor(df$Year)
df$Publisher[df$Publisher=="N/A"]<-NA
df$Publisher<-factor(df$Publisher)
df<-df[complete.cases(df),]

pubSales<-na.omit(df
    %>% group_by(Publisher, Year) 
    %>% summarise(Global_Sales=sum(Global_Sales))
)
pubSales<-pubSales[order(pubSales$Year),]

top5Pub<-head(unique(pubSales[order(-pubSales$Global_Sales),]$Publisher),5)

ui <- navbarPage("Video Games Sales",
    tabPanel("Publishers",
        mainPanel(
            titlePanel(
                title = "Publishers sales"
            ),
            sidebarPanel(
                radioButtons(
                    "pubOptions",
                    "Options",
                    c("Top 5 Publishers"="topFivePub",
                      "Custom Publishers"="customPub"),
                    selected="topFivePub"
                ),
                uiOutput("customPubUI")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("pubPlot")
            ),
            width=12
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$customPubUI<-renderUI({
        if(input$pubOptions=="customPub"){
            selectInput(
                "selectedPub",
                "Editeurs",
                pubSales$Publisher,
                multiple=TRUE
            )
        }
    })

    output$pubSales<-renderTable(pubSales)
    output$pubPlot<-renderPlot({
        ggplot()+
            if(input$pubOptions=="customPub"){
                geom_line(
                    data=pubSales[pubSales$Publisher %in% input$selectedPub,],
                    aes(x=Year,y=Global_Sales,colour=Publisher,group=Publisher)
                )
            }else{
                geom_line(
                    data=pubSales[pubSales$Publisher %in% top5Pub,],
                    aes(x=Year,y=Global_Sales,colour=Publisher,group=Publisher)
                )
            }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please, if it is possible: provide example data so your question becomes reproducible.

Comment: Does that error come even if you convert Publisher from `factor` to `character`?

Comment: @heck1 I got my dataset from kaggle : https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales

Comment: @Sonny I'll try it as soon as possible

Comment: Something of an aside, but in `read.csv` you can use an argument `na.strings` to tell R the format of `NA` in the data you are reading, e.g. `df<-read.csv("vgsales.csv" , na.strings = "N/A")`, which can save you from having to convert them later.

Comment: @AaronHayman Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
require(shiny)
require(tidyverse)

# Create some sample data:
year <- rep(2000:2018, each=3)

publ <- rep(strrep(c("Pub 1", "Pub2", "pub3"), 1), 19)

Global_Sales <- rep(sample(1:100,19),3)
# Create a observation with NA:
newline <- c(NA, NA, 33)

df <- data.frame(Year = year, Publisher = publ, Global_Sales = Global_Sales)
df <- rbind(df,newline)
df <- na.omit(df)

pubSales<-df %>%  group_by(Publisher, Year)  %>%
  summarise(Global_Sales=sum(Global_Sales)) 

pubSales$Publisher <- as.character(pubSales$Publisher)
```

the error does no longer appear. As long as the data you work with in shiny does not contain factors (which is where the "implicit NA" comes from), the error did not appear with my sample data.

Comment: Thanks. If you have some explanations it would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

The warning pops up because NA is non a level in a factor. It is just missing. The warning reminds you there is a "hidden" level in the factor that will not show up when you perform operations on the factor.

For example, a basic factor:

```
a.factor <- as.factor(c('a', 'b', 'c', NA))
```

Only has 3 levels when we print it or summarise in a quick table:

```
> print(a.factor)
[1] a    b    c    <NA>
Levels: a b c

> table(a.factor)
a.factor
a b c 
1 1 1
```

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe contains unused levels of factors, I use

```
pubSales <- droplevels(pubSales)
```

This removes the unused levels and the error for me.